Numpyro returning error "Type error nuts object is not callable" when running mcmc
I am following the Gaussian Process example in Numpyro Website : https://num.pyro.ai/en/latest/examples/gp.html
When I run MCMC I get the following Error TypeError: 'NUTS' object is not callable
I havent included the get_data function as they are in the link above. But X,Y are (30,) in shape and of type jaxlib.xla_extension.ArrayImpl and the kernel function returns a array of shape (30,30) and of type jaxlib.xla_extension.ArrayImpl.
Any clue what the error is ?
# Kernal Function
def kernel(X,Z,var,length, noise,jitter=1.0e-6, include_noise= True):
    deltaXsq = jnp.power((X[:,None] - Z) /length, 2.0)
    k = var*jnp.exp(-0.5 * deltaXsq)
    if include_noise:
        k += (noise + jitter) *np.eye(X.shape[0])
    return k

# Model
def model(X,Y):
    # uninformative log-normal hyperpriors
    var = numpyro.sample("kernel_var", dist.LogNormal(0.0,10.0))
    noise = numpyro.sample("noise", dist.LogNormal(0.0,10.0))
    length = numpyro.sample("length", dist.LogNormal(0.0,10.0))

    # compute kernel
    k = kernel(X,X,var,length, noise)

    # sample Y according to the standard gaissian process formulae
    numpyro.sample(
        "Y", 
        dist.MultivariateNormal(loc = jnp.zeros(X.shape[0]), covariance_matrix=k),
        obs = Y    
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    X,Y,X_test = get_data() #(30,),(30,),(400,)
    #k = kernel(X = X,Z = X,var = VAR,length = LENGTH,noise = NOISE)

    NUM_WARMUP = 1000
    NUM_CHAINS = 1
    THINNING = 2
    NUM_DATA = 25
    DEVICE = "cpu"
    NUM_SAMPLES = 10
    INIT_STRATEGY = init_to_sample()

    KEY = random.PRNGKey(0)
    k0,k1 = random.split(KEY)

    kernel = NUTS(model, init_strategy=INIT_STRATEGY)
    mcmc = MCMC(
        kernel,
        num_warmup=NUM_WARMUP,
        num_samples = NUM_SAMPLES,
        num_chains = NUM_CHAINS,
        thinning = THINNING,
        progress_bar = True
    )

    mcmc.run(k1, X,Y)


Full Error Message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imantha/workspace/python/tutorials/jax/gp.py", line 82, in <module>
    mcmc.run(k1, X.reshape(-1,1),Y.reshape(-1,1))
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/mcmc.py", line 682, in run
    states_flat, last_state = partial_map_fn(map_args)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/mcmc.py", line 443, in _single_chain_mcmc
    new_init_state = self.sampler.init(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/hmc.py", line 749, in init
    init_params = self._init_state(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/hmc.py", line 693, in _init_state
    ) = initialize_model(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/util.py", line 662, in initialize_model
    ) = _get_model_transforms(substituted_model, model_args, model_kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/infer/util.py", line 456, in _get_model_transforms
    model_trace = trace(model).get_trace(*model_args, **model_kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/handlers.py", line 171, in get_trace
    self(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/primitives.py", line 105, in __call__
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/primitives.py", line 105, in __call__
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/tools/miniforge3/envs/ml3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpyro/primitives.py", line 105, in __call__
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imantha/workspace/python/tutorials/jax/gp.py", line 47, in model
    k = kernel(X,X,var,length, noise)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NUTS' object is not callable


sure, I have updated the question with full error message
